# What exactly could be the reason that my .htaccess file disturbs my script (because of redirecting)?

Tags: php, bash, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I am programming a php model-view-controller.

```
Basic structure:

mvc
|
|app
|  |_ models
|  |_ views
|  |_ controllers
|
|web
   |_index.php
   |_css
   |_js
 ...
```

As so I use my .htaccess file for redirecting the url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mvc/web/

# Let any content of web be shown (css, fonts, images, js)
RewriteRule ^web - [L]

# Lets .css or .js files from other folder through (for app/views/[...]/(css|js)/ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(css|js)$ [NC]

# Rewrites everything else to web/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Because I'm implementing a bash-script editor (ACE) and I would like a linter, I am trying to get shellcheck (https://www.shellcheck.net/) running to do the same thing as in the demo.
Now when I put all needed files in the /web folder and access them directly via `localhost/mvc/web/codeeditor.php` the linting works so i figured out it must be something with the redirection in .htaccess

shellcheck comes with a css and a js file, a js library (all of those get loaded), a php file (Content-type: application/json) and an sh file (ajax request -> php -> executes sh -> returns json) and then there's ofcourse my codeeditor.php (set up correctly because it works in the other directory).

Which of these files or what else could be the reason that the redirection isn't working as I'd like it to :P?